# Plaid client axios "export error" in Supabase Deno edge function

Tags: typescript, supabase, deno, plaid

I'm attempting to implement Plaid using Supabase edge functions, which use Deno. The library is imported using an import map from `https://esm.sh/plaid@15.0.0`. The client instance is created successfully, but when I call `client.linkTokenCreate(...)`, it throws:

```
TypeError: t is not a function
    at _e.exports (https://esm.sh/v128/axios@0.21.4/esnext/axios.mjs:4:5201)
    at R.request (https://esm.sh/v128/axios@0.21.4/esnext/axios.mjs:4:10754)
    at Function.request (https://esm.sh/v128/axios@0.21.4/esnext/axios.mjs:3:792)
    at https://esm.sh/v128/plaid@15.0.0/esnext/plaid.mjs:4:3667
    at https://esm.sh/v128/plaid@15.0.0/esnext/plaid.mjs:4:280828
    at async Server.<anonymous> (file:///home/deno/functions/get-plaid-link-token/index.ts:37:22)
    at async Server.#respond (https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts:221:24)
```

I verified `linkTokenCreate` is a callable function, so perhaps something is up with the `axios` dependency, called within? some module incompatibility?

If I can't get the client to work, could all the calls to the Plaid API be done with raw GET/POST requests?

Answer (score 1):

Oops, figured it out, per one of the Supabase examples. The Deno "compile target" when importing Node modules from `esm.sh` should be specified as a query param, so appending `?target=deno` to the import did the trick:

```
  "imports": {
    "plaid": "https://esm.sh/plaid@15.0.0?target=deno"
  }
```